# What Potential Issues Could Arise if I Name a Custom MUI Component the Same Name as the Out-Of-Box Component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm working on a ReactJS project using [MUI](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/), and I'm theming components to match our company's UX design.

A lot of the components I can customize simply by using the [MUI theme provider](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/). However, there are some components that require a little extra customization (for example adding a "x" close button for the dialogs...or adding some built-in React Hook Form form validation for the TextField).

Currently, I'm using a wrapper and calling these components as the component name but with a prefix (for example MyTextField instead of TextField). **My question is: can I name these custom components with the same name as the out-of-box components (TextField, Dialog, etc.)? Is there a technical issue with this, and/or could I run into issues down the line?**

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do it, but I wouldn't recommend it because it can be a burden to figure out the exact component you need when using code actions in VS Code.